# microsoft sync framework Foreign key violation

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I am implementing the sync framework in my C# windows application.

What I have is a table users, a table actions, and a table userActions which has a foreign key on both tables.

When I'm defining my scope in provisioning, the order is parent then child:

```
DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = .....

DbSyncTableDescription users =
                SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Users", new SqlConnection(ServerConnection));

DbSyncTableDescription userActions =
                SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("UserActions", new SqlConnection(ServerConnection));

userActions.Constraints.Add(new DbSyncForeignKeyConstraint("FK_UserActions_Users"));
userActions.Constraints.Add(new DbSyncForeignKeyConstraint("FK_UserActions_Actions"));

scopeDesc.Tables.Add(users);
scopeDesc.Tables.Add(userActions);
```

My sync should happen when a user is assigned a specific action.

So if I create a user 1 with action x, the user is synced. If I create a user 2 without action x, it won't be synced. so far so good.

If now I assign action x to user 2 and re-apply sync, user 2 is still not being synced.
what i noticed is that in my "ApplyChangeFailed" event, I am getting a foreign key violation exception:

> Local Provider apply change failed: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserActions_Users". The conflict occurred in database "LocalGenUM", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.

I have been stuck with this for weeks. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Fx doesn't care about the FKs. the constraints you add during provisioning is only as far as when creating the tables. During sync, it doesn't care about it.

Sync Fx syncs by table. When you added user 2 and skip it synching, when you modify action x to assign to user 2, it's the action row that was modified, not user 2. so during sync, only action x will be detected as changed and it's the one thats going to be synched. Sync Fx will not grab related data for you (again, it doesn't care about those relationships).

Why wont you let user 2 sync when it's added? if you dont do that, you'll have to hack the change dataset (either in ApplyingChanges or ChangesSelected event)  during sync to grab the related data if they don't exists in the destination table. It just complicates you sync further.

Comment: you are saying that only action x will be detected as changed because that's the row that has been modified, not the user 2. But even if i try making changes to both, sync won't work. What flags a row as changed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help JuneT. We have to go for the hack, is there any chance that you would provide me with an example or hints on how to apply it? I tracked the DataSet on the events you mentioned, I can see 4 columns added for each table in scope (sync_update_peer_timestamp, sync_update_peer_key, sync_create_peer_timestamp, sync_create_peer_key) the keys are of value 0, and the timestamps are 4 digits integers (ex: 2001).

I tried manipulating the timestamp values making the create = update, hoping this makes the system consider it a new record. However, this resulted in errors in the DataSet.

P.S: in dataset, there is a record for the updated user, and records for his actions, but it seems like the sync is ignoring the user, and trying to insert the actions only which is resulting in FK violation errors (ApplyChangeFailed)